# Error while Installing APK Xiami Redmi A4

Tags: android, android-studio

I am installing application on Xiami Redmi A4 and it giving me this error.

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user]

Error while Installing APK
```

Comment: have you logged in Mi Account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On Latest Redmi Device**

Settings > Additional Settings > Developer Options > Developer options: Check the Install via USB option.

Answer (score 0):

follow this step to install APK file

1)Navigate to Setting > Security.

2)Check the option "Unknown sources".

3)Tap OK on the prompt message.

4)Select "Trust".